# How to override core Interface and Model file in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How to override core Interface and Model file in magento2...

I need to remove current password in change password frontend section.In current password validate in `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost` Controller file and its call core interface also .How to remove this.

Edited:
It does not solve my problem ..I want customise core api interface not to add additional functionality...Also AccountManagement.php does not have extension attribute

Comment: What research have you done? There are several ways to modify Magento's functionality, all of them documented here and on the Dev Docs. Check the DevDocs first, then come back here with specific questions.

Comment: I need to remove current password in change password frontend section ..In current password validate in \Magento\Controller\Customer\EditPost Controller file and its call core interface also .How to remove this.

Comment: It does not solve my problem @TBS Mage...I want customise core api interface not to add additional functionality

Comment: I think you need override `changePasswordForCustomer` which is in `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement` file and method only.

Comment: Yes...If i can override this model file and modified this function, then is it working for api?